# Ocaml syntax match with boolean

Tags: syntax, compiler-errors, ocaml

I'm a beginner with Ocaml and I cannot seem to get my head around this syntax.
I have to write a function not that returns the negation of a boolean.

I wrote this:

```ml
let not x = 
    match x with
      true -> false
    | false -> true;


if (not false) then  Printf.printf "True !"
```

But it refuses to compile, could anyone give me a hint ?

The error message is:

`Error: This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type bool`

at the last line.

Comment: Try two semicolons to close the `not` declaration?

Comment: Oh dear !
Thank you !
How do I put the green flag on your answer ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OCaml Syntax Error fixed by double semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045645/ocaml-syntax-error-fixed-by-double-semicolon)

Comment: It was only a guess so I posted a comment. Now I also created an answer which you can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://baturin.org/docs/ocaml-faq/#the-double-semicolon, in interactive REPL you need to use `;;` to end your statements:

```
let not x = 
    match x with
      true -> false
    | false -> true;;
(*                 ^^ *)

if (not false) then  Printf.printf "True !";;
```

In source code, you should use only declarations, and can omit any semicolons (thanks @glennsl):

```
let not x = 
    match x with
      true -> false
    | false -> true

let () = if (not false) then  Printf.printf "True !" (*
^^^^^^^^ *)
```

Comment: This actually solved the problem, thank you.
Yet the possible duplicate post above says that semi colons are useless inside the code and should only be used at top level.
I'm a bit lost.

Comment: If you have a source code file that you are compiling, afaik you can just completely omit the semicolons and it still can distinguish the individual declarations.

Comment: Well that's the trouble, I'm not typing this at top level.
And the code would not compile without the double semi colons, now it compiles and run correctly !

Comment: Yeah, I don't completely understand this behaviour either. All I know is that the single `;` is the sequence operator that separates multiple side-effects in an expression.

Comment: It's because `if ...` is an expression, not a definition. And if you don't separate that expression from the previous one, the compiler thinks they're both part of a single expression. `;;` is the separator here. `let () = if ...` on the other hand is a definition. If you use that instead you don't need the `;;`.

Comment: @glennsl Thanks. I forgot the idiom about having top-level calls as a `let () =` declaration. Haven't done any OCaml for some time…

Answer (score 0):

With your help, that seems to be the code I intended to write:

```ml
let not x = 
    match x with
      true -> false
    | false -> true


let () = 
    if (not true) then
        Printf.printf "True !\n" 
    else
        Printf.printf "False !\n"
```